# Null objects appearing in ObservableCollection using async methods

Tags: c#

I have a LogManager that uses some async methods to add to and read from an (async)observablecollection (both encounter the same error). However when running I sometimes have a null value added to this collection and I can't find out where it is coming from.

I tried add breakpoints on the method Log and the async method with a simple if, but there I don't get any null values. The only place I encounter them is when I'm trying to save the logs to a file, in which they are already added to the collection..

At first I thought it was because I was calling the function too fast (it is in a while true loop, that can be canceled though) because of items being added to the collection while I was retrieving values from them.

Right now I got it partially 'fixed' by removing the null object from the collection when I encounter one, though I find it disturbing as it might be a Log I shouldn't be missing.

I'll continue searching, if anyone notices something or want me to add other methods I used to understand better please let me know, any help is appreciated!

Here is my asynchronous SaveLogs function and SaveLoop:

```
    private static Task SaveLoop(CancellationTokenSource cancel)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int count = MessageList.Count;

                    if (count > SavedLogCount)
                    {
                        await SaveLogs();
                    }

                    if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                }
            }, cancel.Token);
    }

    private static Task SaveLogs(bool startLogging = false)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int count = MessageList.Count;
                int savedLogCount = SavedLogCount;
                int logsSaved = 0;

                Console.WriteLine("{0} logs to save", (count - savedLogCount));

                SavedLogCount = count;

                if (count > savedLogCount)
                {
                    string logPath = "logs\\";
                    string logFile = StartTime.ToString("MM-dd-yy_HH-mm-ss") + ".log";
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);

                    if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
                    }

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, !startLogging))
                    {
                        int item = -1;
                        try
                        {
                            for (int i = savedLogCount; i < count; i++)
                            {
                                item = i;
                                LogMessage currentMessage = MessageList[i];

                                writer.Write("({0})", i);

                                if (currentMessage == null)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Current message is null, setting count back to {0} and removing", i);
                                    writer.WriteLine("Null message");

                                    count = i;
                                    // This is something I don't really want to use
                                    MessageList.Remove(null);
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    writer.Write("[{0}][{1}] ", currentMessage.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), currentMessage.Level.ToString());
                                    writer.Write(currentMessage.Message);
                                    writer.WriteLine(" ({0} - {1})", currentMessage.Method, currentMessage.Location);
                                }

                                logsSaved++;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error on item {0}", (savedLogCount + item));
                            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", e.Message);
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        }
                    }
                    SavedLogCount = count;
                }
            });
    }
```

---

### Optimized code (I hope?)

If not, please tell me what I'm doing wrong or where I could improve, thanks in advance!

Improved Log method:

```
    public static void Log(LogMessage logMessage, [CallerMemberName]string method = "", [CallerFilePath]string path = "")
    {
        logMessage.SetCaller(method, path);
        if (!logQueue.Post(logMessage))
            Console.WriteLine("Could not add message to queue");
    }
```

New AddLogsToCollection method:

```
    private static async Task AddLogsToCollection(BufferBlock<LogMessage> queue)
    {
        // Repeat while logQueue is not empty
        while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            LogMessage logMessage = await queue.ReceiveAsync();

            // Add to MessageList
            MessageList.Add(logMessage);

            // Add to CurrentMessageList
            CurrentMessageList.Add(logMessage);

            // Add to FilteredMessageList
            if (logMessage.Level >= FilterLevel)
            {
                FilteredMessageList.Add(logMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Improved SaveLoop task:

```
    private static Task SaveLoop(CancellationTokenSource cancel)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int logsInQueue = logQueue.Count;

                    // Check if there are any new logs to be processed
                    if (logsInQueue != 0)
                    {
                        // Copy queue to temporary currentQueue, so new logs can be added at the mean time
                        BufferBlock<LogMessage> currentQueue = logQueue;
                        logQueue = new BufferBlock<LogMessage>();

                        // Mark the currentQueue as complete
                        currentQueue.Complete();

                        // Start adding the logs to the collections
                        Task addLogsToCollection = AddLogsToCollection(currentQueue);

                        // Wait for the queue to be empty
                        await Task.WhenAll(addLogsToCollection, currentQueue.Completion);

                        // Save current logs
                        SaveLogs();
                    }

                    if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                }
            }, cancel.Token);
    }
```

Changed SaveLogs method:

```
    private static void SaveLogs()
    {
        string logPath = "logs\\";
        string logFile = StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".log";
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);

        bool append = File.Exists(fullPath);

        if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);

        int messageCount = MessageList.Count;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, append))
        {
            for (int i = SavedLogCount; i < messageCount; i++)
            {
                LogMessage currentMessage = MessageList[i];

                writer.Write("[{0}][{1}] ", currentMessage.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), currentMessage.Level.ToString());
                writer.Write(currentMessage.Message);
                writer.WriteLine(" ({0} - {1})", currentMessage.Method, currentMessage.Location);
            }
        }

        SavedLogCount = messageCount;
    }
```

---

### Optimized code 2

AddLogToCollection:

```
    private static Task AddLogToCollection(LogMessage logMessage)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Add to MessageList
                MessageList.Add(logMessage);

                // Add to CurrentMessageList
                CurrentMessageList.Add(logMessage);

                // Add to FilteredMessageList
                if (logMessage.Level >= FilterLevel)
                {
                    FilteredMessageList.Add(logMessage);
                }
            });
    }
```

SaveLoop method:

```
    private static async Task SaveLoop(CancellationTokenSource cancel)
    {
        string logPath = "logs\\";
        string logFile = StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".log";
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);

        if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 8192, useAsync: true))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("writting logs");
                    LogMessage logMessage = await LogQueue.ReceiveAsync(cancel.Token);
                    await writer.WriteAsync(String.Format("({0}) ", logMessage.LogID));
                    await writer.WriteAsync(String.Format("[{0}][{1}] ", logMessage.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), logMessage.Level.ToString()));
                    await writer.WriteAsync(logMessage.Message);
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(String.Format(" ({0} - {1})", logMessage.Method, logMessage.Location));
                    await AddLogToCollection(logMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Start and Stop Loop methods:

```
    private static void StartSaveLoop()
    {
        SaveLoopToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

        SaveLoopTask = SaveLoop(SaveLoopToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Loop started!");
    }

    private static void StopSaveLoop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop requested");

        SaveLoopToken.Cancel();

        while (!SaveLoopTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(SaveLoopTask.Status.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Loop stopped!");
    }
```

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Have you tried catching this with INotifyPropertyChanged? When null is added, this should also trigger that event and you can see what caused this.

Comment: @Djerry How should I go about doing this?

Comment: @SLaks I'm using [AsyncObservableCollection](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/), which should be thread-safe I think

Comment: Maybe a collectionchanged event is better: take a look at this on msdn --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms653375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @TomVandenbussche: No, it isn't.

Comment: @SLaks Oh okay then I'm mistaken, what could you recommend me using then instead?

Comment: @Djerry I subscribed to the event, however I don't see any null items that are added

Comment: Thread safety is _hard_.   Consider using pure asynchrony without threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use [`BufferBlock<LogMessage>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx); it's an `async`-ready producer/consumer queue.

If `BufferBlock` isn't available on your platform, you can use [an `async`-ready producer/consumer queue I built around a `Queue`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/async-producer-consumer-queue-2-more.html). It uses [`async` locks](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock) and [condition variables](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncConditionVariable) from my [AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com) (which also [contains the `async`-ready producer/consumer queue](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncProducerConsumerQueue)).

**Update:** Your posting looks fine, but your receiving is unnecessarily complicated. I would do something like this:

```
private static async Task SaveLoop(CancellationTokenSource cancel)
{
  string logPath = "logs\\";
  string logFile = StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".log";
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);
  if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);
  using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 8192, useAsync: true)
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
  {
    while (true)
    {
      LogMessage logMessage = await queue.ReceiveAsync(cancel);
      await writer.WriteAsync(string.Format("[{0}][{1}] ", currentMessage.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), currentMessage.Level.ToString()));
      await writer.WriteAsync(currentMessage.Message);
      await writer.WriteLineAsync(string.Format(" ({0} - {1})", currentMessage.Method, currentMessage.Location));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked but BufferBlock doesn't seem to be available in my platform (I thought I was using 4.5, ah well), but I'll be definitely checking out the other links and report back here!

Comment: Have you tried [installing the NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow)? If you're on .NET 4.5, you should be able to get `BufferBlock`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could install it with NuGet, that's done now ;) I'll try to implement this now but it's probably gonna take me a while before I understand it. However I found on your blog you have a post about this which I'll definitely be reading first! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I haven't seen any errors since I've implemented my interpretation of this system! However I don't really know if I'm doing everything correct (maybe some redundant calls), so I added my improved methods to my post. So if you have any time I would greatly appreciate you looking over them :) But still a lot of thanks for the answer, it really pushed me in the good direction plus I learned something new ;)

Comment: I updated my answer with a recommendation. There's no need to switch buffers (in fact, doing so is not threadsafe).

Comment: I tried your method and after a little tweaking (SaveLoop originaly started before the first message was added, resulting in my filename being 0001-01-01_00-00-00.log) I managed to make it work! Also I added the AddToLogCollection method, since I need these to display the logs in a view.

However when I try to cancel the SaveLoop (by adding a break when cancel.IsCancellationRequested), the writing seems to stop but the Task itself doesn't get finished (Task status stays WaitingForActivation).. I added start and stop methods above

Comment: I recommend removing the `Task.Run` and making `AddToLogCollection` a regular method.

Comment: Before I continue, thanks so much for your continued support, really means a lot to me! I tried your suggestion and made it a regular method, but this doesn't really make the SaveLoop get finished.

Comment: It definitely should be stopping. Could you post a new question with your current code?

Comment: Sure, I've posted a [new question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067766/task-iscompleted-stays-false-even-when-cancelisrequested) ;)