# Task.IsCompleted stays false even when CancelIsRequested

Tags: c#, logging, task-parallel-library

In my LogManager, I have an async task that runs a while loop to write log information to a text file (and add it to a collection). When I try to cancel this task, the loop seems to stop (I tried with several Console.WriteLines), but the task however doesn't complete.

Here are the main methods of this class:

```
public static DateTime StartTime;
private static CancellationTokenSource SaveLoopToken;
private static Task SaveLoopTask;

public static void Start()
{
    LogMessage startMessage = new LogMessage("Logging Started");
    startMessage.SetCaller("StartLogging", "LogManager");
    StartTime = startMessage.Time;
    LogQueue.Post(startMessage);
    StartSaveLoop();
}

public static void Stop()
{
    LogMessage stopMessage = new LogMessage("Logging Stopped");
    stopMessage.SetCaller("StopLogging", "LogManager");
    LogQueue.Post(stopMessage);
    StopSaveLoop();
}

private static void StartSaveLoop()
{
    SaveLoopToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    SaveLoopTask = SaveLoop(SaveLoopToken);
    Console.WriteLine("Loop started!");
}

private static void StopSaveLoop()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stop requested");

    SaveLoopToken.Cancel();

    while (!SaveLoopTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Loop stopped!");
}

private static void AddLogToCollection(LogMessage logMessage)
{
    // Add to MessageList
    MessageList.Add(logMessage);

    // Add to CurrentMessageList
    CurrentMessageList.Add(logMessage);

    // Add to FilteredMessageList
    if (logMessage.Level >= FilterLevel)
    {
        FilteredMessageList.Add(logMessage);
    }
}

private static async Task SaveLoop(CancellationTokenSource cancel)
{
    string logPath = "logs\\";
    string logFile = StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".log";
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);

    if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 8192, useAsync: true))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                LogMessage logMessage = await LogQueue.ReceiveAsync(cancel.Token);

                AddLogToCollection(logMessage);

                await writer.WriteAsync(String.Format("({0}) ", logMessage.LogID));
                await writer.WriteAsync(String.Format("[{0}][{1}] ", logMessage.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), logMessage.Level.ToString()));
                await writer.WriteAsync(logMessage.Message);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(String.Format(" ({0} - {1})", logMessage.Method, logMessage.Location));

                if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Previous Start/StopSaveLoop methods:

```
private static async void StartSaveLoop()
{
    SaveLoopToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Console.WriteLine("Loop started!");

    await SaveLoop(SaveLoopToken);
    Console.WriteLine("Loop stoped!");
}

private static void StopSaveLoop()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stop requested");
    SaveLoopToken.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: You probably have a deadlock from the sleep.  Don't mix sync and async.

Comment: @SLaks I've added my previous methods, which I used before fiddling around with them since they stopped working. However I never see the message ´Loop Stopped´. The Task status stays ´WaitingForActivation´

Comment: Please don't write your own logger. This is the first of many heartaches that you will encounter. This problem has already been solved.

Comment: @RyanGates Maybe you're right, but this is the last problem I'm having now, everything else works, so I would be stupid to just erase all my hard work. Also I don't think this problem is 'logger-related', as I would just like to know why this happens in case I would need something similar in another context (which I probably will)..

Comment: @RyanGates i would encourage everyone to use one loggers after suffering from different "already build" solutions...

Comment: I'm unable to repro this [using this code](http://pastebin.com/bnmJQVLP). Can you modify the pastebin to fail?

Comment: @StephenCleary First I tried finding any diffirences between what you wrote and what I have, but I couldn't really find any. Afterwards I copied my complete class to another project (console app), and tried something similar to what you did, and for some strange reason it worked! Very annoying however, since i've been looking there a while now when there was nothing wrong with it. I don't understand why it fails in my wpf app though. The start and stop are called on Application_Startup and Application_Exit, but I don't see the problem in that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be seeing a deadlock situation that I describe [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). If the `Application` start and exit events are run within the WPF UI context (which I suspect they are), then the `SaveLoop` would try to finish its `Task` on the UI thread (which it cannot, because the `Exit` event is blocking the UI thread waiting for the `Task` to complete).

You could just ignore the problem (all files are properly closed, but buffered data may be lost). Or you could tweak your solution to support a clean shutdown.

One tweaking option is to run the log writer on a background thread (either using `Task.Run` to wrap `SaveLoop` like you were doing before, or using `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await` in `SaveLoop`). The problem with this approach is that it may not play well with `AddLogToCollection` if the collections are data-bound to UI elements.

Comment: I tried both ConfigureAwait and Task.Run, both worked perfectly! Thank you for this :) However I seem to get this exception: "A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". I know this is probably nothing bad, but is there a way to catch this? I tried try catch in the SaveLoop, but it's still thrown before I can catch it

Comment: "First chance" exceptions are intercepted by the debugger when they're thrown (before your code can catch it). You can either continue your app (allowing your code to catch it) or tell the debugger not to intercept them (Debug -> Exceptions -> uncheck all Thrown boxes).